# Can USA citizen sponsor his sibling for long term stay?

Tags: visa, immigration, resident-permit, greencard

Can a USA citizen sponsor his sibling who is currently living in another country (India) for permanent stay or long term stay in USA?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a US citizen who is 21 or older can petition his/her sibling to immigrate to the US by filing form I-130. A sibling of a US citizen is in the F4 category. According to the current [visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-bulletin.html), visa numbers are now available for F4 petitions filed about 14 years ago for people born in most countries (15.5 years ago for people born in India, 22 years ago for people born min Mexico, 19+ years ago for people born in the Philippines).

Comment: Does that mean it takes 15.5 years to get the permanent stay visa for the sibling in India?

Comment: @user5155835: yes, if the sibling and their spouse were both born in India

Comment: @user5155835 That's the current wait time. The time may decrease, or stay the same, or increase in the future.